# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseFirestore":

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

I have a problem that I cannot seem to resolve. I have tried all of the solutions listed here previously, but nothing is resolving the error. I am building an app using Flutterflow.io, which is a low-code platform. Everything has worked great for a local iOS build using Andriod Studio up to today (Andriod build is still working), but now the CocoasPods and Firebase are not connecting. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseFirestore":
```

In Podfile:
FirebaseFirestore (from `https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git`, tag `8.6.0`)

```
cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 2.5.0, which depends on
  Firebase/Firestore (= 8.5.0) was resolved to 8.5.0, which depends on
    FirebaseFirestore (~> 8.5.0)
```

I also receive this message from the run mode.

"You have either:
* out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
* changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/Auth` inside your development pod `firebase_auth`.
You should run `pod update Firebase/Auth` to apply changes you've made."

I have tried updating the pods, the repo, run `pod update Firebase/Auth`, and delete the podfile.lock folder, but to no avail. Everything seems to point to the same issue with the Pods and Firestore not communicating. I apologize for my lack of expertise as I am new to any type of computer programming.

Answer (score 6):

Worked for me with this fix:

1. Go to `/ios` folder inside your Project.
2. Delete `Podfile.lock` (`YourProject/ios/Podfile.lock`) if you haven't.
3. Open your `Podfile`, also in your `ios/` folder.
4. Locate this bit:

```
target 'Runner' do
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.6.0'
```

1. Change the `tag => '8.6.0'` to `tag => '8.5.0'`
2. Run `pod install` again. Make sure you are inside the `ios/` folder. (`cd ios`)

Then try `flutter run` again outside the ios folder, and should run.

Hope this helps with the Firestore issue.

Comment: You shouldn't delete Podfile.lock.

Comment: This solution works, but the tag can be different as it gets updated with new releases. The error message should say the tag version needed (In February 2023 it is '10.3.0')

Answer (score 5):

**2022**

`in <project folder>/ios/Podfile Change tag to 8.15.0`

```
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.15.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer that worked for me is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70029467/3120387

i prefer that answer because nothing needs to be inserted or manually changed in the podfile.

1. Go to /ios folder inside your Project.
2. Delete Podfile.lock (YourPoject/ios/Podfile.lock)
3. Delete Project.Workspace file.
4. Run pod install --repo-update (Make sure your cd into the iOS directory of the flutter app)
5. Run flutter clean
6. Once complete, rebuild your Flutter application: flutter run

Answer (score 1):

2023

in /ios/Podfile Change tag to 10.12.0, depending on what the latest version is by the time you're seeing this.

The latest version can be found here.

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core/ios/firebase_sdk_version.rb

```
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.12.0'
```

Then - pod install

Answer (score 0):

Apply same code inside pod file  in ios folder of flutter

```
  target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.9.1'
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
```