# Unable to run flutter ios app due to 'FirebaseStorage/FIRStorageTypedefs.h' file not found

Tags: flutter

I created a new application using `flutter create .` and i am using flutter v 2.10.3
When i try to run flutter run on ios i am getting

```
'FIRStorageTypedefs.h' in framework 'FirebaseStorage' (loaded from 'FirebaseStorage') 1 error generated.


Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'FirebaseStorage/FIRStorageTypedefs.h' file not found
/Users/bilalrabbi/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage-10.3.2/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseStoragePlugin.m:6:8
```

I also tried to run the following commands

```
pod install --repo-update

sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

pod install

flutter clean
```

but none of them resolve the issue.

Comment: I found an GitHub issues that's similar to yours. Can you try update the firebaseSDK like the answer in there. https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9014#issuecomment-1172918356

Comment: Can you please show where update needs to be done. which file or if you have a screenshot

Comment: you can follow the answer here, and change the tag version
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69306897/9661936