# Flutter: [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseFirestore"

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

I am trying to run `pod install` but I am getting the following error message:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseFirestore":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    FirebaseFirestore (= 8.9.1, ~> 8.9.0)

  In Podfile:
    FirebaseFirestore (from `https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git`, tag `8.9.0`)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies: `FirebaseFirestore (from `https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git`, tag `8.9.0`), FirebaseFirestore (= 8.9.1, ~> 8.9.0)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

I tried following the solution in this post: [CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseFirestore":](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69016782/cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod-firebasefirestore) which was to add `pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.9.0'` in my Podfile but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: You should remove the `Podfile.lock` first, then run `pod repo update` then `pod install` see if that will fix your issues.

Comment: Didn't work. It gives the same error